# Where did Processing Algorithms go?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have recently installed QGIS 2.8.2 on my Windows 8.1 laptop with the stand alone .exe installer.  The processing toolbox is missing the GDAL/OGR, GRASS, QGIS algorithms, Saga and the Orfeo Toolbox from the processing toolbox which I have on my 2.8.2 installation on a Windows 7 machine using the same installer file.  I have checked the plugin options and all of them are set to activated.  Also the paths are set too and they were pointed at C:\Porgra~1\Wein\apps\"module folder"

I have tried changing it to what is recommended in Joseph's comment to the .qgis path under the users directory but with no change to what is shown[image]

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: All the tools should be there is v2.8 (I can see them in my version).  How did you install QGIS (e.g. stand-alone, via OSGEO4W, or compiling your own binaries)?  You need to provide more detailed information.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @MappaGnosis, check that your **Processing** plugin is up-to-date with your QGIS 2.8.2 (_Plugins_ > _Manage and Install Plugins_ ) and check that the providers for the plugin (_Processing_ > _Options_ > _Providers_) are activated and their path are set to the correct folder (e.g. my SAGA is located in _C:\Users\Me\.qgis2\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the toolbox, change from "simplified" to "advanced" interface to see the grouping into different algorithm providers (GDAL/OGR, GRASS, ...)

The algorithms are all there, they are just not separated by provider if the simplified interface is activated.

Comment: I never understood what this simplified interface was good for and who really needs that . And actually the functions of other providers like GRASS are filtered out and even not retrievable by the search.